# Failed to execute Cassandra CQL statement, while reading from Ignite Cache

Tags: apache-spark, jar, cassandra, ignite, spark-shell

I am trying to integrate ignite with cassandra. I set up the configuration and started the ignite node. But I can not insert/read data from Ignite cache/cassandra db. I created Keyspace and table in the cassandra. And inserted some values. But when tried to read the values , the exception arises. Same thing happened when I tried to insert some values.

My Ignite version is 2.6 and cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | spark version is 2.3.0 | scala version is 2.11.8 | cassandra driver core 3.0.0 | guava 19.0 |

This is ignite configuration.

config3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Cassandra connection settings -->
    <import resource="file:/etc/ignite/config/cassandra_config/connection-settings3.xml"/>

    <!-- Persistence settings for 'cache1' -->
    <bean id="cache1_persistence_settings" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.persistence.KeyValuePersistenceSettings">
        <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource" value="file:/etc/ignite/config/cassandra_config/persistence-settings-3.xml" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Ignite configuration -->
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

        <!-- Enabling ODBC. -->
        <property name="odbcConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.OdbcConfiguration"/>
        </property>

        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <!-- Configuring persistence for "cache1" cache -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="cache1"/>
                    <property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
                    <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>

                    <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStoreFactory">
                            <property name="dataSourceBean" value="cassandraRegularDataSource"/>
                            <property name="persistenceSettingsBean" value="cache1_persistence_settings"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>

                    <!-- Query fields configuration -->
                    <property name="queryEntities">
                        <list>
                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                                <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                <property name="valueType" value="java.lang.Integer"/>
                            </bean>
                        </list>
                    </property>

                    <!-- Query fields configuration END -->
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!--
                        Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                        instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                        to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                    -->
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                    <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

connection-settings3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="loadBalancingPolicy" class="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.TokenAwarePolicy">
        <constructor-arg type="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.LoadBalancingPolicy">
            <bean class="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.RoundRobinPolicy"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cassandraRegularDataSource" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.datasource.DataSource">

        <property name="readConsistency" value="QUORUM"/>
        <property name="writeConsistency" value="QUORUM"/>
        <property name="loadBalancingPolicy" ref="loadBalancingPolicy"/>

        <property name="contactPoints">
            <list>
                <value>127.0.0.1</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

persistence-settings-3.xml

```
<persistence keyspace="ignite" table="cache_test" ttl="86400">

    <keyspaceOptions>
        REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3}
        AND DURABLE_WRITES = true
    </keyspaceOptions>

    <tableOptions>
        comment = 'Cache test'
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.2
    </tableOptions>

    <!--<keyPersistence class="java.lang.String" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="key" />
    <valuePersistence class="java.lang.Integer" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="value" />-->
    <keyPersistence class="java.lang.Integer" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="key"/>
    <valuePersistence class="java.lang.String" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="value" />

</persistence>
```

The error message which I got is,

```
ERROR CassandraCacheStore:586 - Failed to execute Cassandra CQL statement: select "value" from "ignite"."cache_test" where "key"=?;
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to execute Cassandra CQL statement: select "value" from "ignite"."cache_test" where "key"=?;
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.session.CassandraSessionImpl.execute(CassandraSessionImpl.java:167)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStore.load(CassandraCacheStore.java:189)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheStoreBalancingWrapper.load(CacheStoreBalancingWrapper.java:98)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadFromStore(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:327)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.load(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadAllFromStore(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadAll(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:400)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$18.call(GridCacheAdapter.java:2046)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$18.call(GridCacheAdapter.java:2044)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext$3.call(GridCacheContext.java:1435)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6695)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$2.body(GridClosureProcessor.java:967)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to prepare Cassandra CQL statement: select "value" from "ignite"."cache_test" where "key"=?;
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.session.CassandraSessionImpl.prepareStatement(CassandraSessionImpl.java:621)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.session.CassandraSessionImpl.execute(CassandraSessionImpl.java:137)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to establish session with Cassandra database
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.session.CassandraSessionImpl.session(CassandraSessionImpl.java:555)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.session.CassandraSessionImpl.prepareStatement(CassandraSessionImpl.java:603)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.withFallback(Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback;Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
```

To start spark-shell Am using the following command

```
    bin/spark-shell --conf "sparkor.extraClassPath=/etc/ignite/libs/*:/etc/ignite/libs/optional/ignite-spark/*:/etc/ignite/libs/optional/ignite-log4j/*:/etc/ignite/libs/optional/ignite-yarn/*:/etc/ignite/libs/ignite-spring/*:/etc/ignite/libs/ignite-cassandra-store/*"
 --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/etc/ignite/libs/*:/etc/ignite/libs/optional/ignite-spark/*:/etc/ignite/libs/optional/ignite-log4j/*:/etc/ignite/libs/optional/ignite-yarn/*:/etc/ignite/libs/ignite-spring/*:/etc/ignite/libs/ignite-cassandra-store/*"
 --packages org.apache.ignite:ignite-spark:2.3.0
--repositories http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite
```

Comment: `ignite-spark` 2.3.0 obviously conflicts with `Apache Ignite` 2.6.0. It's not version of Spark, it's version of Ignite.

Comment: which ignite is suitable with spark 2.3.0?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea about spark version differencies :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the Guava version. I added guava 19.0 to $IGNITE_HOME/libs/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.withFallback(Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback;Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;

This looks like you've got a JAR hell, i.e., your Cassandra version is not compatible with your google common util version. What build/dependency system are you using?

Comment: I am running ignite in spark-shell.

bin/spark-shell --conf {list } --jars /opt/cloudera/test/ignite/google-collect-0.5.jar --packages org.apache.ignite:ignite-spark:2.3.0 --repositories http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite

Comment: I think that you should not specify google-collect version here as it clashes with cassandra.

Comment: I did not specified earlier. At that time I got the same error

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to re-tag your question as `spark`, and make it about dependencies, not Ignite configurations.

Comment: I added the spark tag.

Comment: You also need to specify your exact launch command and its verbose output.